# Firebase Storage : transcode media files from their source format into versions that will playback on different clients (Android, iOS, Web)

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, transcoding, video-conversion

I am storing the different video file formats provided by my website users in Firebase storage. Since I don't want to restrict my end users to a particular file format, but at the same time ensure that the provided media file can be seamlessly viewed across different clients, I want to transcode them to one particular format (probably mp4).

Is there any support for this in Firebase Storage or any other external feature which will allow me to do this?

I would have done this video transcoding on my application server, however then I cannot upload videos to Firebase storage from my application server because Firebase storage only supports uploading from client app.

Comment: Firebase Storage is just Google Cloud Storage with some client libraries for mobile development.  You can use your Firebase Storage bucket in the same way that you would use a Google Cloud Storage bucket, which means all the same tools apply.

Answer (score 3):

You can use google app engine according to this document:
[gcp-integration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration)